# Doesn't call Facebook loginButton didCompleteWithResult

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I followed the [tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift) here to integrate Facebook login on my application. I can login successfully with that button, but it doesn't call my method `didCompleteWithResult` upon login to fetch user details. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: FBSDKLoginButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func configureFacebook()
    {
        loginBtn.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
        loginBtn.delegate = self
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            let strFirstName: String = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
            let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
            let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!
            print("Welcome, \(strFirstName) \(strLastName)")
            //self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: where you called this method configureFacebook, are you connected the delegate in your xib

Comment: I was wondering about that also. The tutorial asked to create a method, but there was no invoking of that method. Sorry. I'm quite new to Swift, when you said delegate in my xib, did you meant creating a delegate of my button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option-1**

I dont know where you add this method in here I submit answer in dynamically , customize your self..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   configureFacebook() // if you want here add here or else if you want to load the facebook details in Button action add there 
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



func configureFacebook()
{
    loginBtn.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
    loginBtn.delegate = self
}
```

**option-2**

if you add the delegate in directly in your viewcontroller do like for example

[image]

Comment: Both options work, but I decide to go with the safer option 2. Thanks!